# How do you send equivalent to gtag(config) in measurement protocol?

Tags: google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I'm trying to migrate to GA4, but I need to use measurement protocol. I am successfully sending events to GA with POST requests based on this documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events

Unfortunatelly I can't figure a way to send a config request which is described in https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/configure

```
gtag('config', 'TAG_ID', {<additional_config_params>});
```

Can anyone show me a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Measurement Protocol, you don't need to set the config. If you are able to send the events using [Offical docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag), then you are all set.

The `gtag('config', 'TAG_ID', {<additional_config_params>});` config is used when you use `gtag` js on the client side. This is not related to Measurement Protocol at all.